# How to remove an extension from iis using web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

This is my web.config and i want to change iis with it, but in localhost it breaks my site with error 500.

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: What error do you receive? `Error 500` isn't very descriptive.

Comment: @DGibbs
I use this **<remove fileExtension=".json" />** and the problems is solved.
Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Buetto, just add this line to your web.config:

```
<staticContent>
  **<remove fileExtension=".json" />**
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

It will change the iis configuration of your server (localhost).

Answer (score 8):

Without the description of the error you are getting I can only presume you are adding a mimetype that already exists in the IIS server.

In these cases or where you are not sure, you can remove the extension prior to adding it, in your configuration file.

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".json" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```